# screen doesn't change using state_manager

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create a state manager in pygame, this is my code:

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)

        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        self.state = "intro"
        self.font_one = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 30)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()

            self.state_manager()

            self.clock.tick(30)

    def state_manager(self):
        if self.state == "intro":
            self.intro()
        elif self.state == "zgame":
            self.zgame()

    def intro(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    self.state = "zgame"

        self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        text_surface = self.font_one.render(
            "Intro",
            True,
            (255, 255, 255),
        )
        self.screen.blit(text_surface, (100, 300))
        pygame.display.update()

    def zgame(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    self.state = "zgame"

        self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        text_surface = self.font_one.render(
            "Game",
            True,
            (255, 255, 255),
        )
        self.screen.blit(text_surface, (100, 300))
        pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
    main.run()
```

I'm not getting any error, it just doesn't work. When I click ENTER the screen always stay with what is inside the intro function. I don't know how but only a couple of times while I was keeping clicking ENTER it actually worked. What could be the problem? Also, is there a better way to handle something like this?

Answer (score 0):

[`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) get all the messages and remove them from the queue. See the documentation:

> This will get all the messages and remove them from the queue. [...]

If `pygame.event.get()` is called in multiple event loops, only one loop receives the events, but never all loops receive all events. As a result, some events appear to be missed. Get the events once per frame in, pass the list of events to functions and methods where they are handled and use the list f events in all event loops :

```py
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.state = "intro"
        self.font_one = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 30)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            event_list = pygame.event.get()                   #<---
            for event in event_list:
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()

            self.state_manager(event_list)                    #<---
            self.clock.tick(30)

    def state_manager(self, event_list):                      #<---
        if self.state == "intro":
            self.intro(event_list)                            
        elif self.state == "zgame":
            self.zgame(event_list)

    def intro(self, event_list):                              #<--- 
        for event in event_list:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    self.state = "zgame"

        self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        text_surface = self.font_one.render(
            "Intro",
            True,
            (255, 255, 255),
        )
        self.screen.blit(text_surface, (100, 300))
        pygame.display.update()

    def zgame(self, event_list):                             #<---
        for event in event_list:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    self.state = "zgame"

        self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        text_surface = self.font_one.render(
            "Game",
            True,
            (255, 255, 255),
        )
        self.screen.blit(text_surface, (100, 300))
        pygame.display.update()
```